# Deploying a standalone J2SE application within JBoss

Tags: jboss, java

I have a run-of-the-mill Java SE server application. In our normal case, we create an installer using NSIS, and run the server as a Windows service using Windows Service Wrapper.  We then have a Start Menu folder, desktop icons, an uninstaller, etc.

We have a potential requirement to run the same program, but deploy it in JBoss. What is the best approach for doing such a thing?

I think the correct scenario is to deploy an EAR file, then access a web page and click a button that says "Start", which will then launch our standard J2SE process. Ideally, this page would know whether the underlying process is running, so it would provide Start/Stop options accordingly.

The key here is to keep it all in JBoss, as opposed to installing our own program like we do now. JBoss is a customer-driven requirement and is not negotiable. Our approach for deploying it is entirely up to us.

Thoughts?

Comment: So what you want is basically to use JBoss instead of the operating system daemon handler to stop and start your program?

Comment: What should trigger jvoss to start and stop your application? You cannot mean it should happen manually?

Comment: No, I want the application to deploy automatically. Let me put it another way. I want to deploy an application in JBoss. Once deployed, the user can go to a web page and be presented with an option to kickoff the server, which is the one that used to run as a Windows process. Does that make sense? Or am I completely breaking the paradigm here?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, you just want to run a java program from a browser instead of locally on a desktop.  You'll need to dive into some J2EE if you're going to be handling any user input (even clicking the button to kick off the code is going to require a servlet).  In this case, an ear is all you need.